# How to change the css style already defined in code?

Tags: html, css

I have a code and there is class and css style in code. I can't see and can't change this css code. So My css dosen't work for this span. But I need to change this css style as I want. I need blue color for span.
How I can do that? Help me asap. Thanks.

```css
.grid {
  display: block;
}

.grid .item {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <p>I need change</p>
  <span class="item" style="color:red;">This is change place!!!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: use !important ...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important tag

```
.grid .item { color: blue !important; }
```